# First column in distinct select is default order if no order by clause is defined

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, distinct

While working I just noted SQL Server order by first, second columns in select list when it has distinct and it is not as per random order or in order records were created.

Can any one please confirm own experience ?

Comment: In short, the only way you can rely on records to be returned on in a certain order is if you use an `ORDER BY` clause. Never assume they will come back in any particular order without this. If you take a look at the query plan (CTRL-L) you will probably see an `ORDER` in it, which SQL Server uses to deliver your `DISTINCT`, but query plans can change between executions of a query, and it's possible in future this will not be the case.

Comment: hash aggregates can be used for distinct as well, so you may not see a sort.  they are more likely to show as row counts increase.  Also, as row counts go up, your plan may go parallel, which could change the order as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the `Distinct Sort` operator is the last one in the query execution plan, then it seems a reasonable assumption that the final order will be by the columns in order. However, if you truly want them to be ordered a certain way, you should *not* rely on this assumption. You ought to explicitly add an `ORDER BY` clause. It just isn't worth the potential small performance gain to risk things not coming out right. There are other operators that can ensure DISTINCTness such as an aggregate. Are you *sure* it will come out sorted?

Hey, what if the engine becomes smart enough to determine that the rows being returned are *already* distinct and nothing further needs to be done (such as ordering or any kind of aggregate or other stream to discard duplicate rows)? This could be fairly easy, depending on whether primary key columns or unique columns from underlying tables are (all) included. For example, if you have a clustered index on `OrderID`, any query that contains `OrderID` where there is no possibility of the value being repeated, is provably distinct already!

It is a bad habit to rely on side-effects of certain operations. Think about views: for a long time, you were allowed to put `ORDER BY` in a view, and it worked, even though it should never have been relied on. Then, people upgraded their SQL Server databases and found--whoops--that the old behavior was no longer supported. I worked with a SQL 2000 database where, after upgrading to SQL 2005 and changing the compatibility mode, several data tables in the front end were no longer sorted--whoops.

And think about parallelism--this breaks a task up into smaller pieces. Parallelism already has been shown to break `Scope_Identity()` in some cases in some versions of SQL Server. And if one worker thread completes before another, its results may be streamed to the client before other threads are complete--thus suddenly changing order.

Do it right. Add an `ORDER BY`. Don't speculate any longer about what would or could or should happen. Or what wouldn't or couldn't or shouldn't.

Answer (score 1):

Checking the execution plan of a query with DISTINCT confirms your observation.